# Sessions working on Heroku, but not localhost

Tags: node.js, session, heroku, passport.js

The following approach works 100% fine when I deploy to Heroku, but doesn't work on localhost. I have my nodeJS server running on port `localhost:8080` and my angular app running on `localhost:4200`. I set all my Access-Control headers appropriately. Is it a cross domain issue, having my session originate from port `8080` and using it on `4200`?

```
app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore(options),
  secret: 'starbucks-sucks',
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 300000
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

Comment: yes you are correct it is an issue of `CORS`

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true` That's what I have as the response headers.

Comment: have you also tried using cors library which is already present `var cors =require('cors'); app.use(cors());`

Comment: Just tried that, does it require more code that what you listed?

Comment: you will first need to install cors ofcourse with `npm install -g cors`

Comment: let me know if either of the method works if not then just for the development purposes you can try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en extension in google chrome when trying to access your website but do remember to turn it off for other websites

Comment: Yes, I have installed it already, the session looks correct, but it's missing `passport: {"user": {...}}` content: `{"data":{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":300000,"expires":"2017-04-26T07:33:23.523Z","secure":false,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}}`

Comment: you mean some part of cookie is missing in session ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142768/discussion-between-glenn-dayton-and-warl0ck).